# Addition of variables in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm trying to get a button to add 3 separate variables together, however it doesn't seem to be working:

This is the JS:

```
angular.module('basket', ['onsen'])
.controller('basketController', function() {
  this.topsQuantity = 1;
  this.bottomsQuantity = 2;
  this.underwearQuantity = 3;
  this.calculator = 0;

  this.pay = function pay() {
    window.alert("Thanks!");
  };

  this.total = function calculator(topsQuantity, bottomsQuantity, underwearQuantity) {
    return topsQuantity + bottomsQuantity + underwearQuantity;
  };

});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<label ng-model="basket.total">Total: {{basket.total}}</label>
        <div  style="width: 100% !important; position: fixed; bottom: 10px;">
          <ons-button modifier="cta" onclick="basket.total">
          <!--<ons-button modifier="cta" onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('Laundries.html', { animation : 'slide' } )">-->
            Calculate Total <ons-icon icon="fa-angle-right"></ons-icon>
          </ons-button>
        </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Prehaps you want to use this.topsQuantity etc instead inside the method and skip the arguments?
I have no idea what the rest of the code I supposed to do.
I see no relation at all between the controller and the view.
Please provide a runnable Code Snippet and remove all irrelephant code.

Answer (score 0):

There are all kinds of mistakes in yout code:

1. You better understand the different between this and $scope in AngularJS context.

this.[propertyName] in javascript is a declaration of a property named [propertName] inside of an object.

In AngularJS - $scope is a member that inside of it you should declare all the variables that you used in your template (your html).

2. Cant see in your code if you declare the controller,
   expecting somewhere:

   ng-controller='basketController'
3. You named your module 'basket' and you use the variable 'basket' in your HTML (although it was not declared in your controller) - you should decalre it on your $scope.

So in your case it should be:

```
angular.module('basket', ['onsen'])
   .controller('basketController', function() {
       this.topsQuantity = 1;
       this.bottomsQuantity = 2;
       this.underwearQuantity = 3;
       this.calculator = 0;

       this.pay = function pay() {
           window.alert("Thanks!");
       };

       $scope.total = function calculator(topsQuantity, bottomsQuantity, underwearQuantity) {
           return topsQuantity + bottomsQuantity + underwearQuantity;
       };

   });
```

(mind the $scope.total)

and your HTML should be something like this:

```
<label>Total: {{total()}}</label>
```